# JS and PHP Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get the user permission using FB.login JS call. Now when user goes to another page 
I'm trying to fetch his fbuid assuming that he does not need to give the permissions again

i.e.

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
  'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();
```

But I always get 0 instead, What exactly I'm doing wrong?

P.S
I don't want to redirect user to the permission dialog using JS redirect that's why I used JS FB.login

Comment: Look at last section, “Integration with the Facebook SDK for JavaScript” here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

The sessions for JS and PHP must be in the same go. When JS finishes logging in, a cookie is set with the signed request, as long as the same session is reloaded the PHP SDK should be able to recognize it and return a valid user for the `getUser()` call.